# Lexik JWT returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am using LexikJWTBundle for a RESTful API.

Login works just fine and I get my token. But when I make a GET request I get a 401 with no content.
The Authorization header seems ok since I get this in the profiler: 
Request Headers: authorization: Bearer {token}
Request Server Parameters: HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: Bearer {token}

The 401 I get is from: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Security/Firewall/JWTListener.php#L80

I've tried different solutions but still it's not working.

Would you have any idea on how to resolve/debug this?

My config:

```
# config.yml
...

lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: %kernel.root_dir%/var/jwt/private.pem   # ssh private key path
    public_key_path:  %kernel.root_dir%/var/jwt/public.pem    # ssh public key path
    pass_phrase:      'TEST'                                      # ssh key pass phrase
    token_ttl:        86400                                   # token ttl - defaults to 86400
```

And

```
# security.yml

security:
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:       [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
# http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/security.html
# set access_strategy to unanimous, else you may have unexpected behaviors
access_decision_manager:
    strategy: unanimous

encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    api_login:
        pattern: ^/api/login # Default: .*
        provider: fos_userbundle

        # form login
        form_login:
            login_path:     fos_user_security_login
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider # Default: my.csrf_provider.id
            # LexikJWT # 09/01/15 - Note: provient de la configuration officielle.
            check_path:     api_login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false 
        anonymous: true # Default: ~

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        lexik_jwt:
            authorization_header: # check token in Authorization Header
                enabled: true
                prefix:  Bearer
        anonymous: true

access_control:
    # Secured part of the site
    # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
    # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
    - { path: "^/api/contacts$", roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [POST] }
    - { path: "^/api/users/dt$", roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [GET] }
    - { path: "^/api/users$", roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [POST] }
    - { path: "^/api",       roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, ROLE_API] }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found a solution on the same problem

Here my security.yml

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        provider:   user_db
        form_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            username_parameter:       _username
            password_parameter:       _password
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        lexik_jwt:
            authorization_header: # check token in Authorization Header
                enabled: true
                prefix:  Bearer
            throw_exceptions:        false     # When an authentication failure occurs, return a 401 response immediately
            create_entry_point:      true      # When no authentication details are provided, create a default entry point that returns a 401 response
            authentication_provider: lexik_jwt_authentication.security.authentication.provider
```

My problem was the username and the password parameters. I change **"username"** by **"_username"** and **"password"** by **"_password"**

Answer (score 2):

You should add the `ROLE_API` in the `role_hierarchy` of your security.yml :

```
role_hierarchy:
    # ...
    ROLE_API: [ROLE_USER]
```

Then, users ranked with `ROLE_API` can access routes restricted to `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`.

Also, if you are using a web server, try to use your application using the built-in server (i.e. `app/console server:run`).

Apache seems to modify the token in headers.

Answer (score 0):

LexikJWTBundle generates token so user's credentials are valid. 
Problem occurs when you try to access secured routes (behind "^/api" path).

You should definitely check roles assigned to user. Maybe ROLE_API is missing and user is not fully authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was that the provider was missing in the api firewall. Hence it has to be in api_login AND api.