401 Unauthorized when validating JWT in Symfony API
I'm facing an issue with my Symfony backend when trying to validate a JWT token via a POST request to my /api/token endpoint. The React frontend retrieves the token successfully, but the server responds with a 401 Unauthorized status. I’ve checked the token and it seems to be valid, but the server refuses to authenticate it.
Here's what I have:
Frontend Code:
const authenticate = async () => {
    const token = Cookies.get('authToken');
    console.log('Retrieved Token:', token);

    if (token) {
        try {
            const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
            console.log('Decoded Token:', decodedToken);

            // Check token validity
            if (decodedToken && decodedToken.exp) {
                const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                if (decodedToken.exp < currentTime) {
                    console.error('The token is expired');
                    logout();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            const response = await fetch('https://mysite/api/token', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                credentials: 'include',
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                setIsAuthenticated(true);
                return true;
            } else {
                console.error('Error validating token on server');
                logout();
                return false;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during authentication:', error);
            logout();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Token is not present');
        return false;
    }
};

Backend Code:
namespace App\Controller;

use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\TokenExtractor\AuthorizationHeaderTokenExtractor;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class TokenController extends AbstractController
{
    private $jwtManager;

    public function __construct(JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwtManager)
    {
        $this->jwtManager = $jwtManager;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/api/token", name="api_token", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        $tokenExtractor = new AuthorizationHeaderTokenExtractor('Bearer', 'Authorization');
        $token = $tokenExtractor->extract($request);

        if (!$token) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('Token not found');
        }

        try {
            $jwtTokenData = $this->jwtManager->parse($token);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log('Token parsing error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            throw new AccessDeniedException('Invalid token');
        }

        $userEmail = $jwtTokenData['email'] ?? null;

        if (!$userEmail) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('User not found in token');
        }

        return $this->json(['message' => 'Token validated']);
    }

Current Behavior:

When I call the /api/token endpoint with a valid token, I receive a 401 Unauthorized response.
The token appears to be well-formed and valid when decoded.

What I've Checked:

The token generation process returns a valid token.
The token is being correctly included in the Authorization header.
Both the signing and validating processes use the same secret key.

Questions:

What could be causing the 401 Unauthorized response despite the token appearing valid ?
Are there any additional checks I should implement to debug this issue ?

Edit :
Here is my security.yaml file :
    firewalls:        

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # Firewall pour la connexion
        api_login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        # Firewall pour créer un utilisateur
        api_create_user:
            pattern: ^/api/createUser
            stateless: true

        # Firewall pour les API protégées, après l'authentification
        api_protected:
            pattern: ^/api/protected
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~

        # Firewall général pour le reste des endpoints API
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~


        
    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
[...]
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }


And here is my lexik bundle configuration :
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem'
    public_key: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem'
    pass_phrase: 'C3c!_Est_uNE_Passphr@se!'
    token_ttl: 3600 # in seconds, default is 3600
    user_id_claim: "email"


    token_extractors:
        authorization_header:
            enabled: true
            prefix: Bearer
            name: Authorization

        cookie:
            enabled: false
            name: BEARER


Hi @KevSIO please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27961635/1245926
If this doesn't help publish your firewalls setup and Lexik bundle configuration to complete your question context.

Hi @Luismi, Because it didn't work, I have updated my original post. Thanks for the help

Don't see anyhing evident for me. Are you using nelmio/cors-bundle to provide CORS headers support? If so please provide related config too.
